# Comparing lists selecting the value and putting it into another list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 lists (which came from original one list) each with 2 same headers so column A is Tag Number, column B is Length, column C Tag Number, column D Length. Because additions on both lists column A and column C are not equal but a high proportion are the same. So I want to put lengths of cables in D put into the corresponding B with same Tag number.

No idea where to start

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want that lengths on column D should be the ones on B having the Tag as a reference.

The formula VLOOKUP() should work for that (place the formula on cell C2 and drag it):

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,A:B,2,false)
```